# dojo:how to know whether a event handler is bound to a particular dom element

Tags: dojo

Say for example i have clickHandler a function, then i do

```
dojo.connect(domEl,'click',clickHandler).
```

Is there any wayto check whether clickHandler is used as a click event handler for domEl using dojo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For example:

```
var clickHandler = function(evt) {
    var domEl = evt.target;
    // Now domEl is dom node where the click ocurred
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry if i have drafted the question differently.

But, actually i want to know whether dojo has some function like ,     
 dojo.isTheHanlerPassedAsArgumentAttachedToAnyDom(clickHandler) 

which may return some thing like {el:domElement, events:['click']}.

If an handler is attahed to more than one event say click, mouseover for the same dom then,
 dojo.isTheHanlerPassedAsArgumentAttachedToAnyDom(multihandler) 

may return some thing like  {el:domElement, events:['click', 'mouseover']}.

Comment: You changed the question, right? You are asking something different now. I answered a similar (but not identical) question a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112481/dojo-which-events-are-attached-to-an-element/6145949#6145949 . It's time to sleep here, if your still in trouble tomorrow, leave a comment and I'll check back to you.

Comment: yes...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112481/dojo-which-events-are-attached-to-an-element/6145949#6145949 answered my question.